# Why doesn't .vimrc get executed?

Tags: bash, vim, archlinux

When I try to use `. .vimrc` it gives and error:

```
bash: runtime! command not found
bash: syntax: command not found
bash: filetype: command not found
bash: filetype: command not found
```

It just randomly stopped working for no reason, all other dotfiles seem to work fine. The `.vimrc` contains this:

```
runtime! archlinux.vim
set number
set noswapfile
set nobackup
syntax on
set autoindent
set smartindent
set smarttab
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set incsearch
set hlsearch
```

It also gave an error inside a comment when it was there.

Comment: Are you trying to execute the `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.` (or `source`) command is a `bash` command which reads a file (which should be a valid `bash` script) in the context of the current shell instance.

The `.vimrc` file is *not* a `bash` script, it's something that's read and processed by `vim` rather than `bash`.

It's no different to trying to compile C code with a Pascal compiler. The file content is not suitable for what you're trying to do with it. The `.vimrc` file should be automatically picked up next time you run a `vim` instance.

Comment: oh alright thank you, I always thought you needed to use the `source` to start the thing or so

Answer (score 6):

`~/.vimrc` is the runtime configuration file for `vim` i.e. the file will be read by `vim` when it starts and all the statements are `vim` specific.

As you are trying to `source` the file in `bash`, you are getting the errors as `bash` has no idea of the `vim` specific statements like `runtime`, `syntax` etc.

Comment: when I source the ~/.vimrc I get this error. I have `syntax on` in the beginning of `~/.vimrc` and I get `bash: syntax: command not found...`

Answer (score -1):

use `vim`or`vi` instead of `source` command to activate `.vimrc`.Because `.vimrc` is not `*.sh` like `.bashrc` and etc.

Comment: @kkuilla This exactly answers the question. The .vimrc is not intended to be sourced; someone attempting to apply the .vimrc commands would have to do so by invoking vim.

Comment: @kkuilla "Accepted answer has the same content" seems to contradict the idea that this answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @kkuilla you are free to do so, of course, but the question of my preference doesn't come into it, since I prefer not to delete answers for no reason, just as I prefer not to delete answers for the wrong reason.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson But where is the benefit of an answer with the same content as the accepted one (and the accepted one is three years old and is more extensive). Repeating answers doesn't improve the quality

Comment: @jeb You'd have to ask the answerer (or someone else who claims there's a benefit). That said, many questions have redundant answers. The up/down votes help discern the merits of each.

Comment: @L. Scott Johnson@jeb I'm so sorry for bring the unpleasant. I just want to give the directer answer to solve this question.  Yours both advice and critic is helpful for me. The up/dowm votes can really describe the  benefit of each answer. By now, no one supported me. I accept it and I have to claim that when I wrote this answer,never see else answers.

Comment: A more direct answer can be better; or of course a more detailed answer can be. Either way, thanks for contributing to SO.